# how to convert list containing ' : ' to dictionary in python

Tags: python

I am new to here and asking a question relating to python.

I have a list of city's name, population and area, for example:

```
city:NewYork population:30 area:1000
city:LosAngles population:3 area:500
.....
```

but the data is in a list, e.g.

```
list[0] = 'city:NewYork population:30 area:1000'
list[1] = 'city:LosAngles population:3 area:500'
```

I would like to convert this list to dictionary list, 
the result like to be:

```
result[0]["city"] =NewYork
result[0]["population"] = 30
```

I tried many methods, but dont know how to solve it.
Can anyone help me?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name; it masks the built-in type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split on spaces, then on colons:

```
result = [dict(item.split(':') for item in value.split()) for value in inputlist]
```

where `inputlist` is the original list of strings.

Demo:

```
>>> inputlist = '''\
... city:NewYork population:30 area:1000
... city:LosAngles population:3 area:500
... '''.splitlines()
>>> [dict(item.split(':') for item in value.split()) for value in inputlist]
[{'city': 'NewYork', 'area': '1000', 'population': '30'}, {'city': 'LosAngles', 'area': '500', 'population': '3'}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works!! but it says ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #6 has length 1; 2 is required when processing some big files, then what's the problem?

Comment: @user3240660: you have at least one item where there is *not* a `:` in `item`; so `"city population:30 area:1000"` or an empty line or similar. Perhaps the last line is empty?